# Amount Textbox Validation uisng jquery

Tags: jquery, html, validation, textbox

I have two textbox txt1,txt2.I want jquery validation for below opeartion using html.

When i entered text in txt1 at the same time amount must be displayed in txt2.For every keypress,keyup and keydown.then it must allow only numbers.And must be auto formetted to decimal.If i press 12 =12.00.

```js
function isNumeric(elem) { 
 var num= /^[0-9]+$/;
 if(!elem.value.match(num)) { 
 var maxlimit= elem.value.length-1;
 elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, maxlimit); }

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='txt1' 
onkeydown="isNumeric(document.getElementById('txt1')); document.getElementById('txt2').value=document.getElementById('txt1').value" onkeypress="document.getElementById('txt2').value=document.getElementById('txt1').value;" onkeyup="isNumeric(document.getElementById('txt1'));document.getElementById('txt2').value=document.getElementById('txt1').value;"/>
<input type='text' id='txt2' />
```

auto formet to decimal missing.

Comment: Could you supply your html so that any potential response is more clear?

Comment: What have you tried?Share your code